# How to get last item from array of object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have JSON object from server and requirement is to always display last item from the array `items`. how can i achieve that task using AngularJs or native JavaScript ?

Below case i have to display text `Chief Administrative Officer`.

main.js

```
  angular.forEach($scope.rcsaErhTreeData, function(val) {
      angular.forEach(val, function(val) {
          console.log('this is the array value', val[0].text);
      });
  });
```

json.js

```
[{
    "uid": null,
    "index": 0,
    "selected": null,
    "expanded": null,
    "id": 2701,
    "text": "BAC Enterprise Wide",
    "parentId": 0,
    "items": [{
        "uid": null,
        "index": 0,
        "selected": null,
        "expanded": null,
        "id": 4114,
        "text": "Chief Administrative Officer",
        "parentId": 2701,
        "items": []
    }]
}]
```

Comment: yourArray[yourArray.length - 1].text

Comment: array[array.length-1]

Comment: items[items.length - 1]

Comment: Please search before asking a question.

Answer (score -1):

if you try the following code in your context you will get the result.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(items[items.length - 1]));
```

The console will show you the stringified output...

Thanks,
Paras

Answer (score -2):

I am not a Angular.js programmer, but the concept would be to:
1. Either do it in a loop and overwrite the variable value with the next value, that way, the last one will persist.  -- Not recommended due to performance issues, and using a loop when it can be done without a loop.
Pseudo code:

```
var outVal='';
angular.forEach($scope.rcsaErhTreeData, function(val) {
      angular.forEach(val, function(val) {
          outVal = val[0].text);
      });
  });
console.log('this is the last item value', outVal);
```

2. Another approach would be find the length of the val array, and go to its last index to fetch its value.  I am not a pro in this language so cannot give an example code.  Sorry about that.